# What do Msgsrvr and Scientia-ssdb do?

Tags: operating-systems, ports

I'm having a task in a computer security class in school where I'm supposed to scan a host for open ports in order to find out what services are being run there. I have found out (among other things) that the scanned host has an open port 8787 and "Msgsrvr" is being run there, along with Scientia-ssdb on port 2121. What are they, and is it a potential security risk, i.e. should the ports be blocked by the scanned host?

Comment: Wikipedia has a comprehensive list of ports at "List of TCP and UDP Ports".  You should look there.

Answer (score 1):

It's an FTP server from "scientia-ssdb":

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/unable-to-list-the-directory-after-changing-ftp-port-from-21-a-4175454098/